# Adding to database without refreshing the page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I add a model in my index action, the create action is invoked that adds an instance of the model to the database. This is the following create action:

tracks_controller.rb

```
def create
    @track = Track.new(params[:track])


    if @track.save
        redirect_to(root_url) //Want to change this!
    else 
        @tracks = Track.all
        render :action=>"index"
    end
end
```

Where you can see that I am redirected to my root url (where I want to be) everytime create is invoked. However, how can I carry this out without refreshing the page? Since tracks are being played, I do not want the page to be refreshed whenever something is added to the database.

If I change this line to `render :action=>"index"`, then I receive the following error in my `index.html.erb` file

`undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

```
15: <p>Database is empty!</p>
16: <%else%>
17: <br>
18: <% @tracks.each do |track| %>
19: <div id="list_container">
20:     <ul>
21:         <li class="list_container">
```

How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: the form to add a new record is in index page?

Comment: Debadatt has a good answer for you with a little exception, every time you'll add a new record it will go again trough database to fetch all records and display them, instead u can use ajax to prepend/append one last created record to the list, it will be faster this way.. if there won't be too many records you can use Debadatt exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**form**

```
<%= form_for @track, remote: true %>
  form fields
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/tracks/create.js.erb**

```
<% if @track.valid? %>
  $(".tracks").prepend('<%= j(render(@track)) %>'); // make sure you have _track.html.erb
  $("ID OR CLASS OF YOUR FORM")[0].reset(); // this will clear your form inputs
<% else %>
  alert('Something Went Wrong');
<% end %>
```

**app/views/tracks/index.html.erb**

```
<div class="tracks">
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
  <%= render :partial => 'track' %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

**app/views/tracks/_track.html.erb**
some code here to show track:

```
<div>track.id</div>
<div>track.name</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`index.html.erb` needs the `@tracks` variable. Therefore, you have to set it before rendering the page.

For example:

```rb
def create
  @track = Track.create(params[:track])

  @tracks = Track.all   
  render :action => "index"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest, quickest way to get it is to add `:remote => true` to you `form_for`!

Answer (score 1):

If you are posting track from a form then make the remote to true
like

```
<%=form_for @track, :remote => true do |f| %>
    your input fields
   <%end %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id="track_list">
<%= render :partial => 'tracks_record' %>
</div>
```

_tracks_record.html.erb

```
<% @tracks.each do |track|%>
your code
<% end %>
```

in controller

```
def create
  @track = Track.create(params[:track])

  @tracks = Track.all   
  respond_to do |format|
   format.js
  end
end
```

Create one js.erb file for create.js.erb

```
<% if @track.valid? %>
('#track_list').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "tracks_record" ) %>');
<% else %>
alert('Could not save');
<% end %>
```

This will refresh the data and populate the new entries without refreshing the page.

Comment: why would you render all records each time a new one is added? isn't much better to just add the created one to the existing list?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I can't comment on Debadatt's suggestion but I found it much better than the top post. My only notes are to change this to

```
def create
 @track = Track.create(params[:track])

 @tracks = Track.all   
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js
 end
end
```

to this:

```
def create
 @track = Track.create(params[:track])

 @tracks = Track.all   
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
 end
end
```

And this:

```
('#track_list').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "tracks_record" ) %>');
```

to this:

```
$('#track_list').html('<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => "tracks_record" ) %>');
```

Great suggestion thanks Debadatt